# mean stack - mean init throws error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm just getting started with mean stack. 
I'm following instructions from http://www.mean.io/#!/ to get started with this.

I have installed mean stack as instructed here, by

```
sudo npm install -g meanio
```

But when I try to create an app with this

```
mean init myApp
```

It displays this error in the terminal and terminates

```
Cloning branch: master into destination folder: myApp

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
```

Not sure what is this; and I can't even figure out what's wrong. 
Can any body tell me what's wrong on this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: do you have permissions to the directory you run `mean init ..` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as though you don't have Git installed. Trying running:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

Once that completes, run:

```
mean init myApp
```

You should then be good to go!